# Why can't i navigate with my hamburger-menu on mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, css, nav, hamburger-menu

First of all URL ( http://www.munksgaard.one )

As you can see if your on mobile (on desktop, scale the website down under; width 665 px.) I have a hamburger menu. It works "perfect" on desktop, and i can click the links "forside" and "showroom" (the other pages haven't been uploaded yet) and navigate. As soon as i try this on Google Chrome on iPhone SE, it doesn't work, and gives me the url http://www.munksgaard.com/# insted of /shoowroom or /forside.

How do I fix this? What is wrong?

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
  height: 0px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
.logo {
  height: 70px;
  width: auto;
  background: none;
}
.navi {
  display: none;
}
.forsidetags {
  display: none;
}
.dropbtn {
  line-height: 200%;
}
.hamburger {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.cross {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 65px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.menu {
  z-index: 1000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  width: 100%;
  background: #131313;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-image: none;
}
.menu li {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  border-bottom: #1d1f20 1px solid;
}
.menu li:hover {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
  border-bottom: #1d1f20 1px solid;
}
.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #fff;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.menu a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.glyphicon-home {
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.slideshow {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.slideshow img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px #aaa;
}
.salepoint img {
  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
}
#tekst1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#text11 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
#tekst2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#tekst22 {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.salepoint {
  border: solid 2px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.artikel h2 {
  line-height: 0.7;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
footer {
  background: black;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.socialmedia {
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
}
.socialmedia img {
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline;
}
.socialmedia1 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.socialmedia1 img {
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.show {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%
}
.show img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.show1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 40%;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.show1 img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Cecilie CSS */

.produkt.six.columns {
  margin: 2px;
  width: ;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.produkt-billede {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
}
.produkt-tekst {
  max-height: 300px;
  width: 37%;
  margin: 5px;
  float: right;
}
a:hover {
  color: white;
}
@media (max-width: 665px) {
  .opening {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 665px) {
  .menu,
  .hamburger,
  .cross {
    display: none;
  }
  .salepoint {
    display: none;
  }
  .navi {
    display: block;
    background: black;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    z-index: 1000000;
  }
  .kurv {
    height: 40px;
    width: auto;
    background: none;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 12px;
  }
  .logo2 {
    height: 70px;
    width: auto;
    background: none;
    float: left;
  }
  .logo {
    display: none;
  }
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 1.2rem;
  }
  li a,
  .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  li a:hover,
  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: black;
    color: white
  }
  a:hover {
    color: white;
  }
  li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    min-width: 110px;
    z-index: 10000;
  }
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: white
  }
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }
  .slideshow {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 15px auto 15px auto;
  }
  .forsidetags {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  /* Cecilie CSS */
  .produkt.six.columns {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 20px;
    float: left;
  }
  .produkt-billede {
    max-height: 300px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
  }
  .produkt-tekst {
    max-height: 300px;
    width: 35%;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
  }
  .produkt-oversigt {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="da">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <title>Herregård Møbler</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <button class="hamburger">&#9776;</button>
    <button class="cross">&#735;</button>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <div class="navi">
      <img class="logo2" src="img/logo2.png" alt="Herregård-logo">
      <img class="kurv" src="img/kurv.png" alt="kurv">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">FORSIDE</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropbtn">PRODUKTER</a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="stole.html">Stole</a>
            <a href="#">Borde</a>
            <a href="#">Sofaer</a>
            <a href="#">Kommoder</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="showroom.html">SHOWROOM</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropbtn">KONTAKT</a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Om os</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <img class="logo" src="img/logo2.png" alt="Herregård-logo">
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <a href="index.html">
          <li>FORSIDE</li>
        </a>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropbtn">PRODUKTER</a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="stole.html">Stole -</a>
            <a href="#">Border -</a>
            <a href="#">Sofaer -</a>
            <a href="#">Kommoder</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="showroom.html" class="dropbtn">Showroom</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropbtn">KONTAKT</a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Om os</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <article>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="slideshow">
        <img class="mySlides" src="img/slide1.png" alt="slideshow1">
        <img class="mySlides" src="img/slide2.png" alt="slideshow2">
        <img class="mySlides" src="img/slide3.png" alt="slideshow3">
        <img class="mySlides" src="img/slide4.png" alt="slideshow4">
      </div>
    </div>

    <img class="forsidetags" src="img/forsidetags2.png" alt="forsidetag">

    <div class="salepoint">
      <img src="img/levering.png" alt="lastbil">
      <p>Hos Herregård Møbler tilbyder vi fri levering i hele Danmark for varer købt i vores webshop</p>
    </div>
    <div class="salepoint">
      <img src="img/kvalitet.png" alt="kvalitet">
      <p>Vi er dedikeret til altid at levere den bedst mulige kvalitet og den sikreste fragt.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="salepoint">
      <img src="img/garanti.png" alt="garanti">
      <p>Vi tilbyder op til 20 års udvidet garanti på vores møbler, hvis de registreres her.</p>
    </div>

  </article>

  <footer>
    <div class="socialmedia">
      <img src="img/facebook.png" alt="Facebook">
      <img src="img/instagram.png" alt="Instagram">
      <img src="img/linkedin.png" alt "LinkedIn">
    </div>

    <div class="socialmedia1">
      <img src="img/visa.png" alt="Visa">
      <img src="img/mastercard.png" alt="Mastercard">
      <img src="img/maestro.png" alt "Maestro">
    </div>
  </footer>

  <script>
    var slideIndex = 0;
    carousel();

    function carousel() {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      slideIndex++;
      if (slideIndex > x.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
      }
      x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
      setTimeout(carousel, 6000);
    }

    $(".cross").hide();
    $(".menu").hide();
    $(".hamburger").click(function() {
      $(".menu").slideToggle("slow", function() {
        $(".hamburger").hide();
        $(".cross").show();
      });
    });

    $(".cross").click(function() {
      $(".menu").slideToggle("slow", function() {
        $(".cross").hide();
        $(".hamburger").show();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

^ This is the HTML for "forside" and the CSS-file we use on the website + jQuery at the bottom.

Comment: Please avoid doing a complete code dump—try reducing your issue into a minimal, concrete and verifiable example.

Comment: Sorry. I will remember that next time. Still new to the site :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are listening to `click` events.
To get things to work on (some) iDevices you need to also bind to the `tap`event.

```
$(".hamburger").on('tap', function() {
  $(".menu").slideToggle("slow", function() {
    $(".hamburger").hide();
    $(".cross").show();
  });
});

$(".cross").on('tap', function() {
  $(".menu").slideToggle("slow", function() {
    $(".cross").hide();
    $(".hamburger").show();
  });
});
```

Comment: Yeah alright. I'm brand new to jQuery. This took forever to put together, so that will be a lesson for my teacher to teach...

Comment: Don't worry, a lot of people struggle with this because it is just Apple having really weird opinions about what event to fire. You can have the same OSX/Safari version on two different MacBook models and one will give you a click and the other a tap.

Comment: Alright. Thanks anyway :) appreciate the feedback. At least i know why now.

Comment: Since `.tap()` is not a std jQuery function, you bind using `.on()` as I indicated above now.

Comment: ....and remember to accept / upvote answers if they are correct/good ;-) !